# Spark Streaming into HBase with filtering logic

Tags: scala, hbase, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have been trying to understand how spark streaming and hbase connect, but have not been successful.  What I am trying to do is given a spark stream, process that stream and store the results in an hbase table.  So far this is what I have:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{HBaseAdmin,HTable,Put,Get}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes

def blah(row: Array[String]) {
  val hConf = new HBaseConfiguration()
  val hTable = new HTable(hConf, "table")
  val thePut = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(row(0)))
  thePut.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes(row(0)), Bytes.toBytes(row(0)))
  hTable.put(thePut)
}

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
val words = lines.map(_.split(","))
val store = words.foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.foreach(blah))
ssc.start()
```

I am currently running the above code in spark-shell.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
I get the following error in the shell:

```
14/09/03 16:21:03 ERROR scheduler.JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1409786463000 ms.0

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext

at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1033)

at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1017)

at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1015)

at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)

at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)

at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1015)

at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:770)

at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:713)

at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:697)

at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1176)

at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)

at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)

at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)

at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)

at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)

at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)

at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)

at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)

at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

I also double checked the hbase table, just in case, and nothing new is written in there.

I am running nc -lk 9999 on another terminal to feed in data into the spark-shell for testing.

Comment: Could you paste the full stack track? You should be able to get which class causes this error.

Comment: none of the hbase classes are serializable -- make sure that your are not inadvertently serializing them. I don't see anything obvious in your code however

Answer (score 1):

With help from users on the spark user group, I was able to figure out how to get this to work.  It looks like I needed to wrap my streaming, mapping and foreach call around a serializable object:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf 
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext} 
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._ 
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel 
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration 
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{HBaseAdmin,HTable,Put,Get} 
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes 

object Blaher {
  def blah(row: Array[String]) { 
    val hConf = new HBaseConfiguration() 
    val hTable = new HTable(hConf, "table") 
    val thePut = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(row(0))) 
    thePut.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes(row(0)), Bytes.toBytes(row(0))) 
    hTable.put(thePut) 
  } 
}

object TheMain extends Serializable{
  def run() {
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1)) 
    val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER) 
    val words = lines.map(_.split(",")) 
    val store = words.foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.foreach(Blaher.blah)) 
    ssc.start()
  } 
}

TheMain.run()
```

Comment: For clarification to others, the reason it was failing earlier was probably because the function blah was present in the main function. so when blah was used in the rdd.foreach(), the closure of the blah function needed to be serialized, and the closure included other objects in the main function. So the system was inadvertently trying to serialize unnecessary stuff. Moving the blah function to a different object solved this by keeping the closure clean.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a typical antipattern.
See "Design Patterns for using foreachRDD" chapter at http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html for correct pattern.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow, as links may break, even if they include the correct answer. It would be helpful if you could edit the answer to include the relevant material from the link.